# Stacking a large logo onto multiple CSS's

Tags: css, photoshop, slice

I have a basic web design that has a header, a middle box (a big square box below the header) and a footer.

I also have a logo that occupies both the middle and the header, so I am having a difficult time figuring out how to slice my image correctly.  Both the middle and header are both solid colors, but the logo is more extensive.  Is there a way to CSS this style and have the logo lay on top of multiple CSS's?  It isn't a square logo, so I can't just slice it up in Photoshop.

Thanks!

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
#wrapper {
    height: 1.1in;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #0277bc;
    position: relative;
}
#wrapper #logo {
    position: relative;
    top: 200px;
    left: 200px;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this with position:absolute.

Assuming you have a wrapper with an id around all of your content

```
#wrapper {position: relative;}
```

Then give your logo an id and position it relative to the top left corner of the wrapper

```
#logo {position: absolute; top: 200px; left: 200px;}
```

as an example.

You might need to make your logo a png if it overlays the content of the site in any places

Comment: The logo will indeed overlay the header and portion of my middle area.  I edited my original post with the code I am using.

Comment: I see you've accepted my answer, are you happy with the solution?

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative answer to absolute positioning: negative margins.

if your header is 100px tall, and your logo is 150px tall, you can center the logo vertically by using:

```
#logo
{
  margin: -25px 0;
}
```

This will allow you to align the `img` with text-align, or have it inline with text.

Comment: What if I have the headers and footers at 100% in width, thus extending the width of the user's screen, regardless of resolution, and fixed height for both the header and footer.  If I wanted the center of the page (think a table at a fixed length/height) to include my logo always above that table in the same fashion, but always at the same position with the header...do I still want a fixed margin?

Comment: `text-align: center;` will center the `img` in the header. The negative margins are just for escaping the header vertically.

Comment: I guess, one of my tricky issues is, the logo I have is not symmetrical...It is a person throwing an object, and that object (along with a trail emanating from his hand) is a part of the logo...so my png has a lot of white space below and above the trail that I need to use, but the png occupies the entire image like it is a rectangle if that makes sense.  I need to be able to add content directly on top of my logo.

Comment: Here is an example of what I am trying to accomplish, where the image of the guy and the trail has the dimensions of a rectangle:

http://img291.imageshack.us/img291/1226/examplexh.jpg